# how to compare related Sum with a value itself

Tags: django, sum, many-to-many, django-queryset, foreign-key-relationship

```
class Investor(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=16)

class Project(Model):
    plan_finance = IntegerField()

class ProjectProcess(Model):
    project = OneToOneField('Project')
    investors = ManyToManyField('Investor')

class InvestShip(Model):
    project = ForeignKey('Project')
    investor = ForeignKey('Investor')
    invest_amount = IntegerField()
```

How to find the ***Project*** which have already ***finished being financed*** , in other words, **the money received from investors' > plan_finance**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) on the related set and then filter on it.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Project.objects.annotate(invested_sum=Sum('investship_set__invest_amount')).filter(invested_sum__gte=plan_finance)
```

Comment: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'investship_set' into field. Choices are:....(above is the error msg)